# How to proceed in converting the following R code into Python?

Tags: python, r

I have a R code like this:

```
compute_enrichment <- function(dz_vec) {
        dz_vec <- dz_vec[!is.na(dz_vec)]
        n_module_genes <- length(intersect(module_genes,names(dz_vec)))
        module_genes_pct <- n_module_genes/length(module_genes)
        result <- list(escore=NA,norm_escore=NA,pvalue=NA,pct_module_genes=module_genes_pct)
        if (module_genes_pct >= MIN_PCT_MODULE_GENES) {
            result$escore <- abs(sum(dz_vec[module_genes],na.rm=T))
            rand_escores <- sapply(1:N_PERMUTATIONS, function(i) {
                abs(sum(sample(dz_vec,n_module_genes),na.rm=T))
            })
            result$norm_escore <- (result$escore - mean(rand_escores))/sd(rand_escores)
            result$pvalue <- length(which(rand_escores > result$escore))/length(rand_escores)
        }
        result
    }
```

I want to convert this code into  Python. Is there some sort of script available for this? Little heads up to get started would be great. Thanks

Comment: where `module_genes` variable comes from?

Comment: FIRST write some test scripts so you know what output to expect for a given input. Then you can check if your python conversion is doing the same thing as your R version. Of course, with some random sampling in there (the sample() function) you might have some fun doing that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general translation problem would be difficult (and I'm not aware of any automated translation mechanism), and the suggestion made by others to use `rpy` is an excellent one.

However, if you really need to convert this particular code to Python, the job is made easier for this code because it doesn't include many vectorised operations. A pattern to use would be:

1. Code like `dz_vec <- dz_vec[!is.na(dz_vec)]` becomes a list comprehension (though you'd have to have a convention for what to use for `NA`, which doesn't exist in Python, and thus a way to test for that case).
2. `length()` becomes `len()`.
3. `sapply` becomes a list comprehension.
4. Functions like `mean` and `sd` are available in `numpy` (or are easy enough to write yourself).

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to convert it, you can call it from python using [rpy](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 3):

My answer to this question is always: scriptify it, then invoke the script with python using `subprocess`. I like this approach (rather than installing RPy) because RPy won't work with all versions of R (which means recreating your installation if you're not lucky enough to be using the right version), and you won't have to install anything if your R script already runs.

Comment: +1, calling R as a script is a nice simple interface. However, if you need to call this function often with data going back and forth between R and Python, say in an optimization routine, this can get very slow and cumbersome.